# Why am I getting this is undefined when trying to save data into store variable using axios get method?

Tags: axios, vuejs3, pinia

Can someone tell me why I'm getting this error, or point me to working example for such scenario? I have been following example in Pinia documentation.

[image]

[image]

Using:

- "pinia": "^2.1.3"
- "vue": "^3.2.25",
- "vue-router": "^4.0.16"
- "axios": "^1.4.0",
- "vite": "^2.9.5"

TheItems.vue:

```
<template>
    <div>
    Items:
    {{storeItems.items}}
    </div>
</template> 

<script setup>
    /*
    imports
    */
    import { useItemsStore } from '../stores/itemsStore';

    /*
    Store
    */
    const storeItems = useItemsStore();

    /*
    Hooks
    */

    storeItems.getItemsList_API();

</script>
```

ItemsStore.js

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import axios from 'axios';

export const useItemsStore = defineStore('itemsStore', {
    
    state: () => ({
            items: [],
    }),
    actions: {
        async getItemsList_API() {
                await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/items')
                .then(function (response) {
                    response.data.items.forEach(element => {
                        this.items.push(element);
                    });
                    console.log(response.data.items);
                });
              
        },
    },
  });
```

Comment: getItemsList_API( ) is an asynchronous function, so you need to await that when you call it.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer here after posting the question: [Vue.js - axios is undefined when trying to store and display vue-axios response data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52673641/vue-js-axios-is-undefined-when-trying-to-store-and-display-vue-axios-response?rq=2)
I have to use fat arrow in the .then chain in axios call.